# Full state feedback of a closed loop system

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

Does Full state feedback gains affect the dynamic or steady state gain of a closed loop system?

Comment: Yes. including feedback in a closed-loop system (which is the essence of a closed loop) affects the dynamics and steady state. If this is not exactly what you meant to ask, please elaborate further.

Comment: @Petrus1904 So full state feedback gains are there to adjust both the dynamic response and the steady state gain of a closed loop?

Comment: @Petrus1904 as I read that state feedback does not adjust the dynamic response but instead it changes the state of it.

Answer (score 5):

Let me phrase this a bit more elaborate.
Suppose we have a state space system, ie:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$$
Where the dynamics of the system are presented through $A$. For instance, the poles of the system are equal to the eigenvalues of $A$. The steady-state value can be computed by solving $0 = Ax^{ss}$.
Now we have a full state feedback controller $u = -K(x-r)$. The closed loop model is now equal to:
$$\dot{x} = (A-BK)x + BKr$$
Therefore, the dynamics of the system are now represented through $(A-BK)$. This alters both the steady-state value, as this becomes a function of $r$ and the new state dynamics. The dynamic response (so how the model responds to an input) is also different as the forced response matrix $B$ in the open loop model now becomes $BK$ in the closed loop. Furthermore, how the state evolves in time due to this new input is also different, hence the dynamic response is different.

Alternative state feedback notations such as $u = -Kx + r$ exist, and while those do not change how the new input acts on the model, how the states behave due to this input do, thus it still changes the dynamics.

Comment: Thanks @Petrus1904 for your elaboration. This helped to conclude my answer.